# Camel case json when not using ember-data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I am plan use emberjs without ember-data, using Ember.Object. I use rails in back end. The json api rails give is using underscore, I want to change it to camel case in ember end. How to do it effectively? Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/eviltrout/emberreddit.git and http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html

Comment: Yes, I have seen that blog. But it seems he didn't handle camel case thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can have two ways of doing this. The first one could be to modify the json rendered by AMS, using the `key` modifier

```
If you would like the key in the outputted JSON to be different from its name in     ActiveRecord, you can use the :key option to customize it:

class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :body

  # look up :my_attr on the model, but use +myAttr+ in the JSON
  attribute :my_attr, :key => :myAttr
  has_many :comments
end
```

or, writing your own extraction lib relying on the camelize built-in fonction of Ember.String, see http://emberjs.com/api/classes/String.html#method_camelize

Comment: Will the AMS way affect the POST or PUT method? That is: If I $.post to rails server with camelCase ember object, will rails receive de_camel_cased json?

Comment: @xnjiang No, you have to do this in your $post. I think you should take a look at how ember-data serializer is doing it. see https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest_serializer.js#L18 and how the averall serialization is done.